# Version Control - Runtime Error 80070006 The handle is invalid

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I am getting a windows system error when attempting to import a .bas file as a Module in a VBA project. I am able to import manually, and I am able to programmatically import by name, but when I put it into a loop with different import handling conditions, I am getting the error in the picture below.

[image]

Here is an example of my test code to verify that my methods work the way I suspect. This version succeeds:

```
Sub test()

Dim thisBook As String
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "O:\Quality Repositories\Process Checks Workbook Repository\"
thisBook = "Process Control Workbook.xlsm"

For Each element In Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents
    If element.Name = "MacroModule" Then
        If Dir(filePath & "MacroModule" & ".bas") <> "" Then
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.import _
                (filePath & "MacroModule" & ".bas")
            MsgBox ("MacroModule" & ".bas imported")
        End If
    End If
Next element

End Sub
```

And here is the dysfunctional version that handles all the other tile types I might need to import. It succeeds in overwriting all the event handling on the Sheet and Workbook objects, but stops with a system error on the first .frm import or .bas import.

```
Sub import_mods()

Dim filePath As String
Dim thisBook As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim S As String
filePath = "O:\Quality Repositories\Process Checks Workbook Repository\"
thisBook = "Process Control Workbook.xlsm"

For Each element In Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents
    If element.Type = 1 Then 'Modules
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & ".bas") <> "" Then
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.import _
                (filePath & element.Name & ".bas")
            MsgBox (element.Name & ".bas imported")
        End If
    ElseIf element.Type = 3 Then 'Forms
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & ".frm") <> "" Then
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.import _
                (filePath & element.Name & ".frm")
            MsgBox (element.Name & ".frm imported")
        End If
    ElseIf element.Type = 2 Then 'Class Modules
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & "cls") <> "" Then
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.import _
                (filePath & element.Name & ".cls")
            MsgBox (element.Name & ".cls imported")
        End If
    ElseIf element.Type = 100 Then 'Sheet or Workbook modules
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & ".cls") <> "" Then
            Set fso = New FileSystemObject
            Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath & element.Name & ".cls", ForReading)
            Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
                If ts.line <= 9 Then
                    ts.SkipLine
                Else
                    S = S & ts.ReadLine & vbCrLf
                End If
            Loop
            With element.CodeModule
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
                .InsertLines 1, S
            End With
            MsgBox (element.Name & " imported" & vbCrLf & S)
            S = vbNullString
            ts.Close
        End If
    End If
Next element

End Sub
```

The forum posts I have seen with this error usually pertain to websites and coding languages I don't use. I hope someone can offer some suggestions on why one version fails as opposed to the other. As far as I can tell, they are functionally equivalent. I would be very happy to have suggestions on how I can avoid this error and bonus points if someone can explain to me what a handle is.

Just in case it matters, here is a list of the files it searches for. I noticed that the order it searches for them in didn't make sense to me, so I thought it might be valuable information.

[image]

Comment: That code triggers the one rule that every anti-malware program author thought of first when they got started.  Don't expect them to give you a good error message about it, they didn't have to explain it to anybody yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After methodically changing each line one at a time and running the short version of the macro, I was able to identify the source of the issue. I can't explain what causes "The handle is invalid" errors, but I can explain what solved the problem for me:

As the macro executes, if the "element" object it is attempting to remove is not currently executing, the method succeeds in removing that element mid execution. Any line thereafter that refers to "element" will then be invalid because the object no longer exists within the project.

I noticed this because I tested the following code. The change is that I imported the file by name, but then simply tried to create a message box using `element.Name`. which resulted in highlighting the `MsgBox` line with an "invalid handle" error:

```
For Each element In Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents
    If element.Name = "OutsourceModule" Then
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & ".bas") <> "" Then
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Import _
                (filePath & "OutsourceModule" & ".bas")
            MsgBox (element.Name & ".bas imported")
        End If
    End If
Next element
```

That told me that the name itself has to be invalid after removing the element. I addressed the error by creating a String Variable to store the name of the element after removing the element. This allowed me to pass that same name to the import method and again to the message box function!

The following is a perfectly successful version of Version Control for an Excel Workbook. It uses the names of current objects in the project to search a specified file location for exported files of the same name. If it finds matches in that location, then it replaces forms, class modules, and modules with imported versions from the location. If it finds .cls files (exported from sheet and workbook objects) then it deletes the text in those objects, and replaces it with the text of the files with the same names.

```
Sub import_mods()

Dim filePath As String
Dim thisBook As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim S As String
filePath = "O:\Quality Repositories\Process Checks Workbook Repository\"
thisBook = "Process Control Workbook.xlsm"

Dim newString As String

For Each element In Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents
    If element.Type = 1 Then 'Modules
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & ".bas") <> "" Then
            newString = element.Name
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.import _
                (filePath & newString & ".bas")
            MsgBox (newString & ".bas imported")
        End If
    ElseIf element.Type = 3 Then 'Forms
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & ".frm") <> "" Then
            newString = element.Name
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.import _
                (filePath & newString & ".frm")
            MsgBox (newString & ".frm imported")
        End If
    ElseIf element.Type = 2 Then 'Class Modules
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & "cls") <> "" Then
            newString = element.Name
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove element
            Workbooks(thisBook).VBProject.VBComponents.import _
                (filePath & newString & ".cls")
            MsgBox (newString & ".cls imported")
        End If
    ElseIf element.Type = 100 Then 'Sheet or Workbook modules
        If Dir(filePath & element.Name & ".cls") <> "" Then
            Set fso = New FileSystemObject
            Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath & element.Name & ".cls", ForReading)
            Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
                If ts.line <= 9 Then
                    ts.SkipLine
                Else
                    S = S & ts.ReadLine & vbCrLf
                End If
            Loop
            With element.CodeModule
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
                .InsertLines 1, S
            End With
            MsgBox (element.Name & " imported" & vbCrLf & S)
            S = vbNullString
            ts.Close
        End If
    End If
Next element

End Sub
```

One thing to note is that whatever module you store this macro in will not get deleted during execution because it is still running. In that case, the imported version of that macro will get renamed as `moduleName1`.  You can very easily create a separate event or sub procedure in your workbook project to rename that module at a different time.

I am certain that there are more elegant ways to do this but below is a Workbook Event showing how I handled the renaming issue:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

For Each element In Workbooks("Process Control Workbook.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents

    If element.Type = 1 Then 'Modules
        element.Name = Replace(element.Name, "Module1", "Module")
    ElseIf element.Type = 3 Then 'Forms
        element.Name = Replace(element.Name, "1", "")
    ElseIf element.Type = 2 Then 'Class Modules
        element.Name = Replace(element.Name, "Module1", "Module")
    ElseIf element.Type = 100 Then 'Sheet or Workbook modules
    End If
Next element

End Sub
```

I hope this helps someone!